# Is there already a commonly known name for the 'ensure pattern'?

Tags: design-patterns

I use a pattern that I call "ensure" extensively in my repository layer. In short, it does the following when I call an `Ensure(...)` method:

1. It uses the arguments in the method to attempt to populate an entity of a specified type (ultimately from the database),
2. If it finds one then it returns it; f it does not, it saves the entity to the database and return it.

So, my Ensure method ensures that there is always a populated entity with specified properties, irrespective of whether one existed before the call was made.

Is there already a more commonly known name for this pattern?

Comment: Doesn't this pattern break the query / command separation principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)?

Comment: Good question - however, under the hood it does two separate calls. So, it doesn't violate the principle. This kind of pattern is used quite a lot in well written import routines, for example. It's a shame that I cannot find a name for it.

Comment: Are **assertions** what you look for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)

Comment: It's similar except it isn't used for unit testing purposes and returns a whole entity rather than true or false. It's nearer the Ensures method used in coding contracts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.ensures(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: We tend to call it `GetOrCreate`. @JensG I don't think assertions are going to help here. I think the description makes it pretty clear that he wants to return a specific instance - and if it doesn't exist already - create it first. A sort of lazy instantiation, but in this case the database plays a role in it as well.

Comment: I quite like GetOrCreate. It's short enough and is more descriptive than Ensure.

Comment: Hey @Carnotaurus, why did you delete this? Don't worry about the downvote, it's a decent question. You can't reply to this comment while the question is deleted, if you want to further discuss the question I'll be in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). In any case, look up [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), it's a technique that's very close to what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted it for the down vote. I've looked at lazy initialisation but this is really about checking if a record is in the database then if not then put it in there and retrieve the record and populate it in the business layer.

Comment: @MarjanVenema - agree, makes sense. I use `GetFoo(bool canCreate)` in such cases, which let's me control whether or not I really want to create a new `Foo` instance but still have only one method to retrieve `Foo`s

Comment: @MarjanVenema It's also called `get_or_create` in [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/)

Comment: @JensG I dislike that because you then have to go to the docs to find out what `GetFoo(true)` does and how it's different than `GetFoo()` or `GetFoo(false)`

Comment: I've used ValidateXYZ(xyz) to ensure the xyz exists when there's a chance it's already been created. I have no idea whether it has an official name, but it is very useful.

Comment: @Izkata: you could use an enum `(ccReturnNull, ccCreateIfNotExists)` (or some other names) instead of a boolean. I agree with you and [Nick Hodges](http://www.nickhodges.com/post/How-Not-To-Code-2-Dont-Use-Boolean-Method-Parameters.aspx) on this that booleans should be avoided as parameters.

Comment: You state "my Ensure method ensures that there is always a populated entity with specified properties" but according to your point #2 it actually does not - if there was a preexisting entity *with different properties* then you just return it. If you did an insert-or-update instead then it would always have an entity with those properties, and that operation is sometimes called `Upsert`.

Comment: Upsert = InsertOrUpdate

Comment: A long-standing example: open(..., O_CREAT) in POSIX.

Comment: I've seen it used and called "ensure" in code before.

Comment: I've seen and used this pattern as "ensure" before as well, but only when referring to databases. To me, it seems like another instance of say, for example, C++ STL map's array operator - so it's something that makes me think of keyed collections in general.

Comment: Cache? Caching proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your name is correct, Microsoft has a method called **.GetOrCreate(*int id*, ...)** in the *LifetimeContext* class located at System.Composition.Hosting namespace (.NET 4.5) that does exactly this.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.composition.hosting.core.lifetimecontext.getorcreate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But, my opinion is that you are in fact implementing a different version of a **Multiton Pattern** (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)) the only difference from the normal implementation is that instead of having a cache of entities, you are going to the database to check for the "instances", so you could consider changing your method to `.GetInstance(int id)` or even `.GetInstance<T>` in a generic repository.

But your name is also correct, like i said, it´s a different approach.

Comment: +1 for multiton, might also consider this a form of memoization